# Placeholder for multiple select in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html

How to give placeholder for multiple select in angularjs?
Here only if the search_functional_org is selected, then it_domain will be pre-populated.Is there any method to give placeholders to the multiple select.

```
<select class="form-control" id="it_domain" name="it_domain" ng-change="loadChart(1)"
                    ng-model="search_it_domain" multiple
                    ng-options="t for t in it_domains[search_functional_org]">
            </select>
```

Angularjs directive was declared for single dropdown select as:

```
 angular.directive('select', function($interpolate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            var defaultOptionTemplate;
            scope.defaultOptionText = attrs.defaultOption || 'Select';
            defaultOptionTemplate = '<option value="" disabled selected style="display: none;">{{defaultOptionText}}</option>';
            elem.prepend($interpolate(defaultOptionTemplate)(scope));
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: you need to add element under ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using select2 with angularJs then here it is .

```
  $(".js-example-responsive").select2({
      placeholder: "Select a state",
      allowClear: true
    });
```

html

```
<select class="js-example-responsive js-states select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" style="width: 75%" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Mountain Time Zone">
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Central Time Zone">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Eastern Time Zone">
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

[Link For Docs](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)